# apache multiviews, how to disable it

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf

I have a OS X Snow Leropard Server running and I want to disable multivewis from Apache. I could add `Options -MultiViews` to each .htacces file I have, but I guess there must be a global option. Disabling `mod_negotiation.so` renders all pages useless so this is not the option I'm looking for ..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

In case of `Options` either you have to use * or - sign with all or with none; i.e.

```
Options FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

is wrong.

If you are using + or - sign, you have to use for all options i.e.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

Answer (score 4):

In /etc/apache2/httpd.conf you should find the section starting `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">` and remove MultiViews from the Options directive there. The same goes for any other paths if your content isn't in that directory.

As an aside, if you're able to edit the server's main config file you should never have to use .htaccess file. Doing so only slows down the server, makes tracing the configuration harder and makes any use of mod_rewrite a brain-rending disaster.

Comment: I couldn't find <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents"> but I have added the following: (to no success): <Directory "/">  Options FollowSymLinks Options -Indexes Options -MultiViews AllowOverride All </Directory>

Comment: There's no need for your multiple Options directives. If you specify e.g. `Options FollowSymLinks` without any +/- modifiers then that is taken as the complete set of Options. It's generally a bad idea to mix relative and absolute Options arguments, especially on the same line.

Comment: Regarding your choice of Directory path, you should note that any directories "closer" to the real one will take precedence. For that reason you should look through all your config files and possibly any vhost declarations for Options directives that could be overriding your own.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is OS X, one snag I ran into was my user specific declarations (in the users/*username*.conf subdirectory of apache2) had MultiViews turned on, overriding httpd.conf.

MultiViews was substituting /*search*.php for /*search*, messing up the "pretty" Codeigniter urls on my dev machine.